# Sendmail or SSMTP for CronJobs

Tags: cron

I am using a Amazon ec2 instance(cron server with Ubuntu OS) to run all nightly cronjobs. There are some 8 sh files which run @ night. I get email alerts using sendmail for all the 8 sh files status.

Now i need to get a email alert for a particualr sh file, with its execution time duration.
My concerns are :

**->** can i do that with sendmail. if so, were i need to mention the to address, is it in crontab -e, or in that particular sh file.

**->** can i do that with sendmail, or should i go for ssmtp?

--
Thanks,
Anand S

Answer (score 0):

Cron can't send you the execution time. You need a small wrapper which calls your app. You can use the "time" command:

```
@daily time orig-crontab-line
```

Example output

```
user@host> time ls
...

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.003s
```

You can alter the mail recipient with MAILTO. See `man 5 crontab`

Comment: Thanks for the reply guettli,    can you be more specific, like with an example, please..